# How can I sync RememberTheMilk to my Mozilla Thunderbird (or another application)?

Tags: sync, thunderbird

I like RememberTheMilk as a to-do list thing. It syncs well with my android phone, which is important. However, there doesn't seem to be a simple option for syncing RTM with my Ubuntu desktop. I currently use Getting Things Gnome! which is OK, but not ideal: syncing has to be done manually (AFAIK) and weirdly, the extra features of GTG are annoying: since RTM doesn't support subtasks, I'd rather not have the option of subtasks on my desktop to-do widget.

I can sync RTM with my google calendar and use that through thunderbird, but this had some weird effects: for every day where I had a to do item with a deadline in the future (i.e. every day) I had an all day event in my calendar for that event: doubleplus suboptimal.

So is there a better option? Preferably one that fits with thunderbird, since that's where all my other organisational shenanigans are taking place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Tasque](http://packages.ubuntu.com/tasque) [image: Install tasque] is a simple to-do application for GNOME that has Remember The Milk integration. It's very straight forward and syncs in the background, unlike GTG.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This site has 12 different ways to sync with RTM, including Thunderbird, Firefox, Gmail:

http://www.shankrila.com/tech-stuff/top-12-refreshing-remember-the-milk-goodies/